# Drupal 6 login failed, with "too many redirects" error

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication, drupal-6

This morning on a website I need to keep alive on Drupal 6, users can no more log in ! Nothing on the code has been modified since 3 years...

What's going on !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply in the `sessions` table. These table was corrupted.

**Solution is** to open phpMyAdmin or SQL command line and execute the following :

```
REPAIR TABLE `sessions`
```

Hope it helps someone